# Can I create one event handler for all DataGrid controls in my web application?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I wanna execute same functionality for all `DataGrid` controls in my application for  example.. inserted event handler. but without calling it manually. I mean to be called automatically.

Is there anyway to do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Derive from DataGrid and use that class all around your app.  Handle the event(s) in the derived class.

Answer (score 0):

Well why not? Just create a Event handler method and then pass it to each GridView's events like this.

```
 //Example for Click Event
GridView1.Click += new EventHandler(mygeneric_Clickhandler)
GridView2.Click += new EventHandler(mygeneric_Clickhandler)
GridView3.Click += new EventHandler(mygeneric_Clickhandler)

protected void mygeneric_Clickhandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  your implementation
}
```

OR you can declaratively do it via markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"
   click="mygeneric_Clickhandler"></asp:GridView>
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server"
   click="mygeneric_Clickhandler"></asp:GridView>
```